# What's the point of a sling ring?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

Doctor Strange and other sorcerers in the MCU use a tool called a sling ring in order to be able to perform magic.

But why is a physical tool required to perform those mind-blowing magics? Isn't magic supposed to come from a soul?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are only shown to require the sling ring to conjure the portals and travel from place to place. Other spells are performed regularly by people not wearing a sling ring.

There is a scene in *Doctor Strange* where Mordo gives the following explanation of magical relics.

> This is a relic.
>
> Some magic is too powerful to sustain, so we imbue objects with it **allowing them to take the strain we cannot**.
>
> This is the staff of the Living Tribunal.
>
> There are many relics. The Wand of Watoomb. The Vaulting Boots of Valtorr…

Notable in that scene is that Dr Strange then conjures a very similar effect to the staff of the Living Tribunal to spar with Mordo, but it takes him significant effort.

Sling rings aren’t mentioned here, but I think it is a reasonable assumption that the transportation spell would be too draining for an individual to actually do without a sling ring or some other external source of power.

Comment: "Some magic is too powerful to sustain". This is the problem here. Magic is supposed to come from soul and mind. Powerful is a physical adjective like lifting heavy weights.